# RGB LED Diffuser

Tags: rgb

I have come across different techniques for diffusing colors. I found Fresnel Lens can be use for diffusing RGB led colors.Is it worth using it or not. I have tested transparent plastic and some lenses but they are not good. Only white paper I found is best.

If it is worth for using (Fresnel Lens)can you guys tell me about supplier for it as well.

Comment: seems pretty OT

Comment: This is either a shopping question (off topic), or not a good fit because we can't answer whether it is worth it or not.

Answer (score 1):

More data please.
 Power, target, distance, size ... application ?

Fresnel lenses have the advantage of beam shaping with relatively minor optical losses - about 10% typically. The same applies to TIR lenses and reflectors - both of which MAY do what you want. White paper achieves its superior result with a very high optical loss. This may be unimportant or crucial depending on application.

Comment: Hi there: I want diffuser for RGB led. At the moment I am using white paper for it. My colleague told me to use Fresnel lenses. I want to put diffuser on led. Is it possible with Fresnel lens. So I can see mix color from top of led. I tried to search on it but cannot find data regarding mixing RGB led colors.

Comment: That's what you told already, but Russel wants to know what your total setup is for. Are you presenting one nice little colored dot, or are you illuminating a theatre (to mention two extremes)?

Comment: At the moment nice little colored dot.

Comment: I get your point. I need a lens or diffuser which diffuse light first. Then spread that light as well. I hope I have cleared your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that a fresnel lens will work for you in the diffusion of the rgb diode as the diodes are discrete and slightly separated... a fresnel lens would have to be fairly far from the LED in order to not create a bunch of little rainbows.

but a white paper and a fresnel lens would work, or perhaps some sort of white paint on the back of a lens... you need something to break up the directionality and cohesiveness of the three light sources or else you will end up with the multi-color shadow effect: [like this](http://blog.sciencegeekgirl.com/2009/05/27/physics-toys-tuesday-colored-shadows/)

Comment: I have tried white paper with lens though it has some loss but still works best till now for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

- LSD - no not that type - Light Shaping Diffuser - bought in sheets
- Opal glass - has some patterns
- ground glass - readily available
- etched glass - readily available in a local glazier (glass shop)

Comment: guys could you please vote my question.